How do I give role based access control to the users for a hospital management system using enum in python?
I am new to python programming and I need to write a python code for giving access controls to the users based on their roles like doctors, nurses, staffs, managers, etc. using enum implementation. I need this for a hospital management system. I have created an app called core and written the following codes:
in views.py :
from .serializers import UserCreateSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework import status

@api_view(
    ['POST']
)
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user=authenticate(
            username=serializer.validated_data['username'],
            password=serializer.validated_data['password'],
            role=serializer.validated_data['role'],
        )
        if user:
            token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return Response(
                {
                    'token': token.key,
                    'user' : user.username,
                }
            )
        return Response(
            {
                'error': 'Invalid credentials',
            },
            status = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        )

@api_view(
    ['POST']
)
def register(request):
    serializer = UserCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(
        {
            'details': 'User created successfully',
        }
    )

in serializers.py :
from django.forms import ValidationError
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    role = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    role = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['confirm_password']:
            raise ValidationError({
                'confirm_password': 'Passwords do not match',
            })
        return attrs
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop('confirm_password')
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)`

Now my question is : Where do I write the code using enum?? If anyone can help me out with this, please feel free to help
I've having difficult writing the code using enumyour text
